# Get sum of previous 6 values including the group

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to sum up the values for the last 7 days,so it should be the current plus the previous 6. This should happen for each row i.e. in each row the column value would be current + previous 6. 
The case :-

[image: The requested scenario]

(Note:- I will calculate the hours,by suming up the seconds).

I tried using the below query :-

select SUM([drivingTime]) OVER(PARTITION BY driverid ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  from [f.DriverHseCan]

The problem I face is I have to do grouping on driver,asset for a date

[image: scenario]

In the above case,the driving time should be sumed up and then,its previous 6 rows should be taken,
I cant do this using rank() because I need these rows as well as I have to show it in the report.

I tried doing this in  SSRS and SQL both.

In short it is adding total driving time for current+ 6 previous days

Comment: Dear Naved Bhai, for such question where you don't want a generic solution but your problem-specific solution, I believe its always good to add sample temporary table with sample insert into data so that one can suggest and verify solution easily. what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT 
        s.date
        , s.driverid
        , s.assetid
        , s.drivingtime
        , SUM(s2.drivingtime) AS total_drivingtime
    FROM f.DriverHseCan s
    JOIN (
        SELECT date,driverid, SUM(drivingtime) drivingtime
        FROM f.DriverHseCan
        GROUP BY date,driverid
        ) AS s2
        ON s.driverid = s2.driverid AND s2.date BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-6,s.date) AND s.date
    GROUP BY 
        s.date
        , s.driverid
        , s.assetid
        , s.drivingtime
```

If you have week start/end dates, there could be better performing alternatives to solve your problem, e.g. use the week number in SSRS expressions rather than do the self join on SQL server

Answer (score 0):

I think aggregation does what you want:

```
select sum(sum([drivingTime])) over (partition by driverid 
                                     order by date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                                    )
from [f.DriverHseCan]
group by driverid, date
```

Comment: Yeah, I want to show assetId,drivingTime as well in the report, adding those columns in grouping doesn't solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `CROSS APPLY`.

Something like following? :

```
SELECT driverID,
       date,
       CA.Last6DayDrivingTime

FROM  YourTable YT
      CROSS APPLY
      (
       SELECT SUM(drivingTime) AS Last6DayDrivingTime
       FROM YourTable CA ON CA.driverID=YT.driverID
       WHERE CA.date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-6,YT.date) AND YT.date)
      ) CA
```

Edit:
 As you commented that cross apply slow down the performance, other option is to pre calculate the week values in temp table or using CTE and then use them in your main query.

Comment: FYI: I have tested cross apply in a similar query to which my answer is based. Results where the same, but cross apply didn't perform well (14 times slower) compared to self join

Comment: Then other option is to pre calculate values in temp table or using CTE and then use them in your main query.